# MS Bot get current page url

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework

I have created a bot with MS Bot SDK. Then, I want to get the page URL where I'm hosting the bot. I just inject the script to a page to host the bot. But, does anyone who knows how to get the current page URL from C#?

I can see someone is trying to use Activity for getting the URL, but I can't find the right property from Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ChannelData** was designed to enable sending custom information from client to bot, and back.  Similar to Fei Han's answer, you can intercept outgoing messages and provide custom ChannelData for every activity sent.

```
<script>

    var dl = new BotChat.DirectLine({
        secret: 'yourdlsecret',           
        webSocket: false,
        pollingInterval: 1000,
    });

    var urlref = window.location.href;

    BotChat.App({
        botConnection: {
            ...dl,
            postActivity: activity => dl.postActivity({
                ...activity,
                channelData: { pageurl: urlref }
            })
        },
        user: { id: 'userid' },
        bot: { id: 'botid' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));
</script>
```

Then, in the bot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eric, BTW, I have closed the issue on GitHub as well. This makes more sense to me

Comment: HI Eric, is there a way that I can customize the ChannelData within the ClientSide typescript code? To get the same consequence.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "customize the ChannelData within the  ClientSide"

Comment: Hi Eric, I can see your code is working fine and is writing in the embedded page where the bot is being hosted. But, what I really want to do is customizing the ChannelData property by typescript within the source code of [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/src). I don't know which is the best file I should do this, so that I can also either log or manage the state of Activity object from the Client Side. This is one of our requirements, so, do you have any idea how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Hi Eric, I found the solution for this. Actually we modified the ChatBot.js file from [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) for our own usage. Because we would like to modify the embedded bot more flexible. But, I'm not the front-end person, so I was struggling about how do I modify the typescript files to generate our own ChatBot.js in order to pass the page Url. But, I just had a chat with our front-end person, they just put the code to another file which similar with your solution. And your solution is still very helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I just inject the script to a page to host the bot. But, does anyone who knows how to get the current page URL from C#?

If you [embed webchat in your web site](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) and you want to get the URL of the web page where you embed the webchat, you can try the following approach to get the URL and pass it to your bot.

***Pass the URL to bot:***

```
<script>
    var urlref = window.location.href;

    BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: "{directline_secret}" },
        user: { id: 'You', pageurl: urlref},
        bot: { id: '{bot_id}' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));
</script>
```

***Retrieve the URL in bot application:***

```
if (activity.From.Properties["pageurl"] != null)
{
    var urlref= activity.From.Properties["pageurl"].ToString();
}
```